# Mixed percentage algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, percentages

{QUESTION}

A survey is conducted in the 4th and 5th grade of a school about sports.

In 4th grade, 15% of students (males and female) are good, 35% are bad and 50% are indifferent. There are 100 male and 120 female students.

In 5th grade, 25% of students(males and female) are good, 30% are bad and 45% are indifferent. There are 80 male and 100 female students.

Using ANY METHOD of your choice LOGICALLY APPLICABLE, calculate the the total no  of males (4th & 5th) good, bad and indifferent each. Find same for females.

{MY ANSWER}

The 2 given data sets do not intersect. Also each problem has no solution. More data is needed. Is this correct?

{BACKGROUND}

My younger bro approached me to help him out with his assignment. He is not very enthusiastic about academics, so, I first lectured him on how math is life and vice versa, taking math seriously and how he should come for me to tutor him. I then went on further about how the problem has an easy solution after first read - I thought it was just simple mixed percentage problem.

However, upon careful analysis I found I could not solve the problem as I cannot derive a sufficient system of equations to satisfy the equation-unknown-root theorem rendering them underdetermined; I then wrote that the equation has no solution and the 2 given data sets do not intersect. So more data is needed.

However, I'm bugged because of the line in the problem suggesting using any logical means, so I just want to know whether I've missed anything.

*hint* I may be bugged cos it'll really suck to lecture someone about how they should come for tutoring, but couldn't solve a (simple?) problem yourself! So have I missed anything? ;).

Comment: This may help: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html

Comment: As I read the problem, there is no need to find any equations to solve.  Speaking of the fourth grade, we are told that $15\%$ of BOTH males and females are good, and that there are $100$ males...hence $15$ good males.  Trusting that the parenthesis holds for the other designations, we also have $35$ bad boys and $50$ indifferent boys.  If you do not assume that the parenthetic note holds for all three designations then there is not enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: I think @lulu is right about what the person who wrote the problem intended. It's just percentage practice. But the problem is poorly written and most naturally reads as you did, in which case there is insufficient information.

Comment: Percentage practice for senior high schoolers? Doesn't sound right to me, but that would be a shame! Thanks anyway.